# how to tell the button not to segue but still have a segue in the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Is there a way to have the button not segue but still have a segue in the storyboard? The reason I want it to not segue but still have a segue in the storyboard is because I have an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, and put the conditional logic inside it.

Let's say you have a segue called `@"OnMyButton"`, but you do not want to activate it when a certain variable, let's call it `count`, is under ten. Then you can code this logic as follows:

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"OnMyButton"]) {
        if (count < 10) {
            // Count is too low - don't do the segue
            return NO;
        }
        // Fall through to the default, which is YES
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this would work.. but I have to have the don't segue code in an if statement in an IBAction

Comment: @user3294825 Then you should wire the segue from the view controller (instead of wiring it from the button), and trigger it programmatically in the `if` statement by calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OnMyButton" sender:self];`